# amplification of audio signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm trying to write a program that takes two audio files and matches one to the other as best it can. So if I were to give the program two audio files, one of which is just a quieter version of the other one the program should amplify the quieter one to match the other. What functions could I used to achieve what I am looking for? i have used following code lines but it balances both signals but cutting the louder signal. i want the quieter to be equal to louder one

```
% creation of signals
 N=1024;
 n=0:N-1;
 x=sin(2*pi*(2^-7).*n);
 y=2*sin(2*pi*(2^-7).*n+pi/4);
 
 % justify its power 
 x1=x/sqrt(mean(x.^2));
 y1=y/sqrt(mean(y.^2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the ratio of `x` and `y` with the max mean value, for `x` this is 0.5, for `y` this is 1. A way to achieve this:

```
N=1024;
n=0:N-1;
x=sin(2*pi*(2^-7).*n);
y=2*sin(2*pi*(2^-7).*n+pi/4);

% justify its power
x1=x./(sqrt(mean(x.^2)/(max(mean(x.^2),mean(y.^2)))));
y1=y./(sqrt(mean(y.^2)/(max(mean(x.^2),mean(y.^2)))));

figure()
plot(n,y)
hold on
plot(n,x1)
legend('y','x1')
xlabel('n');
```

Results in the following figure:
[image: y and x1 plotted]